# Is it possible to multiprocess tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, tkinter, multiprocessing

I am trying to multiprocess multiple tkinter windows where threading (for long running processes with while loops) in each process will be required. Is this possible?

I have tried to work around this by doing a pure multithread implementation - The entire application starts to turn 'laggy'; hence the attempt now to do multiprocessing. Please see code for a very simplified, basic version of what I am trying to do. There are 2 scripts:

**Main file (to run)**

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import threading
import multiprocessing
import multiprocessing_import_worker

def hello():
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        p_list = ["Hello", "success"]
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=multiprocessing_import_worker.worker, args=p_list)
        p.start()
        root.destroy()

root = Tk()
root.title("Window 1")

statusFrame = Frame(root)
statusFrame.pack()
statusLabelFrame = LabelFrame(statusFrame, text='TEST FRAME', font="Helvetica 8 bold")
statusLabelFrame.pack(fill="both", expand="yes", padx="7")
firstButtonFrame = Frame(root)
firstButtonFrame.pack()
statusbar = Label(statusLabelFrame, text="TEST", width=40, font="Helvetica 8 bold")
statusbar.pack()
b1=ttk.Button(firstButtonFrame, text="START SESSION", width=15, command=hello)
b1.pack(pady=(10,0))

root.mainloop()
```

**Secondary file (to be run as a separate process)**

```
def worker(word, word2):
    import threading
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import ttk
    import os

    print(word)
    print(word2)

    def testThread():
        global word
        global word2
        print(word)
        print(word2)

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    rootWindow = tk.Toplevel()
    rootWindow.title("Window 2")

    statusFrame = tk.Frame(rootWindow)
    statusFrame.pack()
    statusLabelFrame = tk.LabelFrame(statusFrame, text='TEST FRAME', font="Helvetica 8 bold")
    statusLabelFrame.pack(fill="both", expand="yes", padx="7")
    firstButtonFrame = tk.Frame(rootWindow)
    firstButtonFrame.pack()
    statusbar = tk.Label(statusLabelFrame, text="TEST", width=40, font="Helvetica 8 bold")
    statusbar.pack()
    b1=ttk.Button(firstButtonFrame, text="START SESSION", width=15, state='disabled')
    b1.pack(pady=(10,0))

    child_thread1 = threading.Thread(target=testThread)
    child_thread1.start()

    rootWindow.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", os._exit(0))
    rootWindow.mainloop()
```

**Expected results**:

- A tkinter window to pop up titled "Window 1"
- Upon pressing START SESSION, "Window 1" gets destroyed (closes).
- "Window 2" (which looks exactly the same) then pops up, with its START SESSION button disabled.
- Pressing the cross at the top right hand corner closes "Window 2" and ends application.

**Actual results**:

- A tkinter window to pop up titled "Window 1"
- Upon pressing START SESSION, "Window 1" gets destroyed (closes).
- Another "Window 1" (which looks exactly the same) then pops up, with its START SESSION button enabled is not mapped to any command.
- Pressing the cross at the top right hand corner closes "Window 1" and ends application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard way to do this would be for all GUI manipulation to take place in a single process, while other processes will handle any computationally-heavy tasks. As long as there's no heavy computation going on in the GUI process, the application should remain responsive, and you can use cross-process communication to update the GUI with results of the heavy process as needed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! This recommendation makes sense, but I think this is difficult in my case because my long standing process is quit complicated with quite afew variables (to hold results). An example would be how it needs to check if there is incoming data; and if so, update a dictionary (this dictionary is shared with another function that updates it as well). 
I did my due diligence online and found that it is rather complicated to share variables of various data types between processes. 
Do you have a recommendation/ minimal example for such cases? Thanks!

Comment: Moving multi-process variables around in Python is terrible, but because it's a GUI, you can cheat; you don't really care about the speed as long as the user doesn't notice. If I wanted to send an arbitrarily-complex Python object to a GUI process, I would turn it into a json object, use Array('c', ...) to send it to the GUI, and unpack it on the other side. There's probably a better way to do it if that's not fast enough, but as long as you don't need to update the GUI multiple times a second or something, the overhead this would add doesn't matter.

Comment: Definitely not my place to say; but if possible the tkinter guys should definitely do something about this. There will almost always be some form of external i/o that needs to be reflected on the GUI.
Very nice explanations by the way, to my first ever stackoverflow question. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It's possible, but *all* interaction with the GUI must be in a single process. Tkinter itself cannot span processes, nor threads. Your other processes must put work on a queue that the tkinter process periodically polls and acts upon (of course, you could also communicate with any other form of IPC).

The reason for this is that each root window is associated with an embedded tcl interpreter, and this interpreter itself cannot span processes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Looking at my code, the newly spawned process opens its own root window and does not share/ span to the parent process (which in this case is closed) when the new process is spawned. Will it still work in this case? Thanks!